# Calculate row specific based on min

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2),
                 y = c(.9, .8, 1, 1.2, .5, .1))
```

I am trying to multiply each x value by either y or 1, depending on which has the least value.

```
df$z <- df$x * min(df$y, 1)
```

The problem is it is taking the min of the whole column, so it is multiplying every x by 0.1.

Instead, I need x multiplied by .9, .8, 1, 1, .5, .1...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need `pmin` that will go through each value of 'y' and get the minimum val when it is compared with the second value (which is recycled)

```
pmin(df$y, 1)
#[1] 0.9 0.8 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.1
```

Likewise, we can have `n` arguments (as the parameter is `...`)

```
pmin(df$y, 1, 0)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

To get the output, just multiply 'x' with the `pmin` output

```
df$x * pmin(df$y, 1)
```

which can also be written as

```
with(df, x * pmin(y, 1))
```

Comment: yes, this is perfect.  I did not know about the `pmin()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use an ifelse function:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2),
             y = c(.9, .8, 1, 1.2, .5, .1))

df$z = ifelse(df$y<1, df$x*df$y, df$x*1)
```

This will compare the values of each row.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: or: `ifelse(df$y < 1, df$y, 1) * df$x`